Firebase Mobile authetication , cant send recaptcha code ,imean my browser doesnt open, i have set up sha key as well , in play protect ,Saf
In firebase Mobile auth cant send otp when i am in debug mode means app not published on playstore , i have tried everything from sha key to play protect
Hi everyone, I am actually facing a error in  firebase otp sending.
Case :-
I want to have firebase otp authentication
For testing purpose I made a test app and on that test app, it's working fine we are redirecting to the captcha screen (as Using in debug mode) and  otp is sent, but when I use in main app, that Recaptcha screen is not opening and getting error project config. Failed with invalid cert hash.
I have checked signing report multiple times to check valid sha1 and sha2 would be there . Please help me out to find the bug that causes this error
Ps:- both main and test app are in same project of firebase and both have same code of initial activity, even same dependencies (few dagger missing in test) .
Thanks for your help
logs :-
E  [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 18002 Invalid PlayIntegrity token; app not Recognized by Play Store.
2024-04-11 05:26:51.059 32678-32678 FirebaseAuth             com.XXXX.xxxx                      D  Re-triggering phone verification with Recaptcha flow forced for phone number +919@#@**6091
2024-04-11 05:26:51.717 32678-1067  FirebaseAuth             com.XXXX.xxxx                      E  [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with INVALID_CERT_HASH 400
2024-04-11 05:26:52.177 32678-1067  FirebaseAuth            com.XXXX.xxxx                 E  [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
Logs for reference

I have found the solution:

Check if you have added the SHA key in Firebase settings.
Add the Google Console and Play Protect API.
Add App Check in Firebase.
Try changing the project package name (this worked for me).

